# SQL Tables without SQL Server or Express

Tags: sql-server, database, product-development

This question is directed at developers that use database tables in their applications.

Is it possible to create/develop an application that uses a table that was created in SQL Server or SQL Server Express, without having either of those applications installed on the users system/device?

Comment: If you want to use a database file containing tables that was created by SQL Server (Express or other editions), you **must have** SQL Server - no way around this.

Comment: SQL Server LocalDB is very lightweight (stripped down version of Express), although it does require installation

Answer (score 0):

Its depends which type of connection string you have if its local so you need to download and if its not local you can use

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're looking for [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html). This approach uses the filesystem to store data that we can access using standard SQL queries. It requires no additional applications to be installed.